# Extract inner field value from JSON document based on a key using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file with the below format. I want to extract the `name` field value from inside based on the `id` value.
so, if I pass id value as 99900, it should return me DEF. How can I do that using jq.

```
{
  "11213-99900": {
    "cid": "11213-99900",
    "name": "DEF",
    "id": "99900"
  },
  "11213-12345": {
    "cid": "11213-12345",
    "name": "ABC",
    "id": "12345"
  },
  "11272-23456": {
    "cid": "11272-23456",
    "name": "YXX",
    "id": "23456"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `select`:

```
$ jq -r --arg q 99900 '.[] | select(.id == $q).name' file
DEF
```